# Replace concat part of a string in typescript

Tags: angular, string, typescript, concatenation

I have a variable string, because it is inside a textarea. A user can write anything. After that there's a date picker. When I select the date, the value will be written in the textarea after the first part of the string. I have this function on change of the picker

```
concatValue(){
    let dataMsg = "";
    let date: string = moment(dateTime).format('D MMM YYYY, h:mm');
    dataMsg = ". " + date;
    this.message += dataMsg;
  }
```

The problem here, is that if I change date, the string keep concat and don't reset the before value. But I can't reset the entire `this.message` because it include other text. How can I do something like this? For example. First time

```
"Hello there at Thursday 15 October 2020, 19:00"
```

then i wanna change date:

```
"Hello there at Friday 16 October 2020, 15:00"
```

That's what I need instead of

```
"Hello there at Thursday 15 October 2020, 19:00"
"Hello there at Thursday 15 October 2020, 19:00 Friday 16 October 2020, 15:00"
```

Comment: can you share the function that updates/injects the concatenated string in the text area?

Comment: it's concatValue() function. I call that function when I change date in the picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make my own [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so if you need to tweak it to apply to your use case, hopefully you can.  Imagine I have this `Foo` class that takes a `message` and concats dates or times or something onto it:

```
class Foo {
    message: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    concatDate() {
        this.message += " @ " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    }
}

let f = new Foo("hello there");
console.log(f.message); // "hello there"
f.concatDate();
console.log(f.message); // "hello there @ 12:56:10 PM"
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
f.concatDate();
console.log(f.message); // "hello there @ 12:56:10 PM @ 12:56:12 PM"
```

Oops, every time I call `concatDate()` it adds to the end of `message`.  How can I fix it?  Well, one idea is that you can try to look at `message` and *strip off* any date string if one is there.  Like this:

```
class BadFixFoo {
    message: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    concatDate() {
        this.message = this.message.replace(/ @[^@]*$/, "") + 
          " @ " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    }
}
```

It kind of works:

```
f = new BadFixFoo("hello there");
console.log(f.message); // "hello there"
f.concatDate();
console.log(f.message); // "hello there @ 12:56:12 PM"
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
f.concatDate();
console.log(f.message); // "hello there @ 12:56:14 PM"
```

Until it doesn't work:

```
f = new BadFixFoo("what if I use an @-sign in the message");
console.log(f.message); // "what if I use an @-sign in the message"
f.concatDate();
console.log(f.message); // "what if I use an @ 12:56:14 PM"
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
f.concatDate();
console.log(f.message); // "what if I use an @ 12:56:16 PM"
```

See, the method I used to strip off the date just looked for the last `@` sign (after a space) in the `message` and removed it and everything after it.  But if the original `message` has an `@` sign in it, then the stripping will mess it up.  Oops.  Maybe we can write an even more clever way of identifying a date string, but if the user can truly write *anything* for the original `message`, there's nothing we can do to stop them from writing an actual date string.  Do we want to strip *that* off?

---

If not, you need to refactor so that you're not trying to forensically determine what the original `message` was.  Instead, store it:

```
class GoodFoo {
    originalMessage: string;
    message: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.originalMessage = message;
        this.message = message;
    }
    concatDate() {
        this.message = this.originalMessage + " @ " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    }
}
```

This means that `concatDate()` never tries to modify the current `message`.  Instead, it copies the `originalMessage` and appends to *that*:

```
f = new GoodFoo("what if I use an @-sign in the message");
console.log(f.message); // "what if I use an @-sign in the message"
f.concatDate();
console.log(f.message); // "what if I use an @-sign in the message @ 12:56:16 PM"
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
f.concatDate();
console.log(f.message); // "what if I use an @-sign in the mssage @ 12:56:18 PM"
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQLYFMpgHMcAuaCAFwCcBLAOwIG51Nh5aLKBXYc+SgClz4ipDnQIBKFM0yZyAC2oQAdEIiEc0ALzY86ok1kBfGdFa1gYcgBErOflLSzZCpar0boAah0AiaAAC0P5e0LQ4AO7QtuT2Esq8ADLwliA4ACrUuADKVOIOhpgmJqigkDAAQmAAJrDUAB4ISE6YahqiefSFGOYc3LwCbSJknZLSznKKKkOaOjPd0Cay5pY2dg7jE9Cu0x5E2ttT7sI4ypQ4AA7gwPYA9IEA2gB6AQC6AFQAJLcANMG+UlC-iCITCkWi63iSRSYDSmRyowKpmK0FQpXAUGgAHFELVEJsMHxqAQ6LCALJ7EgjGhdUwzDo0ximXpUfp8QSUhniRymFxHIkk2jkykHea8yZuGaiykLJYsNirGJxAnOHbHfSzQ5uAWkkAUk7eYKBI2hcJRJUOBLwZKpDJZHC5RlI4yoEqQACeFmgADNOBZyNQ2Ns8OQNi0MGlyNAQPACBAufQHq8DkmFizoDVqulrbGDvx6gmxloAHzR2MqC6cCDyfMSBZgCJgahRgAKlHgWCUp3OEHgIAAbnEmKZIz6Dma4Ih+L55DgQDHDjhzgD69UszmCPxveqNHXoLd7jO5wuFEucL5TNuVlYLXXTJns8lN9uZnuD8FZ-OkKfzsaAIwAEzEAArAAbMQf4AAzQC2ZIXrIDZNlGE5th2Xb8D2faDtopYQDg5Dwjg8CcKGmEDjgfwAZB1ESHeshXgqN6Qqu65PluO5EG+h6fies6-kEgEgeBUEwWS-5AWBEEAaJF6XuO4JVLUDRNNOPHfnx550ZgD4buxr4MPu3HHupZ7wZgDEWExsTOtpa6PrGemUlxH7GYu-HQIJkmATJ96Ns2YJRKhnZ4RheBYbMuH4YRxGkWF5GUdRkG0QsFmKsx952bpL5OQZ75Hl+bmaAJEnCQALD5ck6BOil1I0U6+BE8hWNA1DetAACS0BVpoYC0IEAC0EDEn1dCLroJwrhlrEOdlJzOQ1TVRq1HVdXhGZ9QEg3DS1fWnuNGpmRgqVWUOU32c+HE4PNjXNctnXdet4lCRB5WwYdGZ+ch4JBehZHYSWZBRfaMWhb28XQFRNFaUdyjXms1nQxmmVsbNGrXYtLVtfda29U9XmgRV9HyVEOLwHi8DTjdS1Y6tPUbVtBAjbts77Rok0IcjM2Xejt00w9uObUNjM7WNMzvcd8OnRz00XfphnBFTmMrfz9NC0zosisVz1-gTb2+UhAUwe2wX2H9EWAwRwMkaD4UJVDKWw4xks2RgOko9zuWHord2049gvbaNe1YAaWteQAHD5sj3mklChjGcbKAAVvAdDTgAOrQAJ3q6aKxBQDioEAA)

Comment: thank you very much! It's working and you have explained everything perfectly. Thanks a lot